# reading from file using fgets() then using information in another function

Tags: c, file, pointers, fgets

I have a text file like this:

```
123-55555-1 10000 0   
123-55533-3 12300 500 
123-99971-3 50000 0 
123-38951-2 350 10  
120-39888-0 4910 100   
121-12345-3 50000 150 
121-xptoz-3 1000 100  
150-23857-1 350000 20000 
521-71750-4 500000 25000 
191-11999-7 1200
```

and what I want is to be able to retrieve this information line by line using `fgets()`. when I read it I want to call another function that uses the line read works the information and put it on a list. The thing is when I try to call in the function and passing the string as an argument it gives me seg error:11. Here is my code.

```
typedef struct identificador_s
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;

} identificador;

typedef struct contaBancaria_s
{
  identificador id;
  int saldo;
  unsigned short int credito;
  struct contaBancaria_s * proximo;

} contaBancaria;

contaBancaria * contaP = NULL;
char contas[] = "contas.txt";
char movimentos[] = "movimentos.txt";

char divideString(char line[], int contagem, char parametro[])
{
  int i = 0;
  char *a = NULL;
  char string1;
  a = strtok(line, parametro);
  while (i != contagem)
  {
    a = strtok(NULL, parametro);
    i++;
  }
  string1 = (char) *a;
  return string1;

}

void contaFill(char line[])
{
  printf("passo -2");
  contaBancaria * p = malloc(sizeof(contaBancaria));
  printf("passo 0");
  int i = 0;
  char parametro1[] = "-";
  char parametro2[] = " ";
  p->id.a = (int) divideString(line, i, parametro1);
  printf("passo 1");
  p->id.b = (int) divideString(line, i += 1, parametro1);
  printf("passo2");
  p->id.c = (int) divideString(line, i += 1, parametro1);
  printf("passo 3");
  /*if(!(validaIdentificador(p-id.a,p->id.b,p-id.c))){
   return;
   }*/
  p->saldo = (int) divideString(line, i += 1, parametro2);
  printf("passo 4");
  p->credito = (int) divideString(line, i += 1, parametro2);
  printf("passo 5");
  printf("%d - %d - %d %d %d", p->id.a, p->id.b, p->id.c, p->saldo, p->credito);
}

void loadFile(char fileType[])
{
  FILE * fp;
  fp = fopen(fileType, "r");
  int size = 100;
  char buffer[100];
  char string1[100];
  if (fp)
  {
    while (fgets(buffer, 100, fp) != NULL)
    {
      puts(buffer);
      if (strcmp(fileType, "contas.txt") == 0)
      {
        contaFill(buffer);
      }
    }
    fclose(fp);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  loadFile(contas);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what the hell is "code format"?

Comment: as you see i put my code in quotes because i don't understand the code option. So it stays all together a little difficult to identify and read.

Comment: yeah i see that,you better try using some editor and indent it properly so that it can become readable.

Comment: but in my code is allways readable when i put it in here its stays like that i dont understand why

Comment: What editor or IDE you use?

Comment: textmate for mac os x

Comment: You make code format by putting four spaces in front of each line.  The `{}` button in the editor does it for you.  But now you have `> ` in front of each line, which is how you indication quotations, not code.  Please fix your question, including the typo `frets`.

Comment: many thx it was that what i was referring. For a long time i tryed to understand that xD now i know.

Comment: @RicardoSacramento I use emacs,it provides me with everything including indentation style for every language.I use it on windows and i am sure there must be a version for mac OS too.And don't try to copy and paste the code write it on own and then the indentation will work properly.

Comment: Reformat done... Ctrl-Shift-F ;-)

Comment: cant anyone reply to my question now that the code is okay xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first call `divideString(line, i, parametro1);`

```
p->id.a = (int) divideString(line, i, parametro1);
```

return value is '1' -> 49

first `'-'` of `line` replace `'\0'` by `strtok`

(E.g. `"123-55555-1 10000 0"` -> `"123\055555-1 10000 0"` meant "123"

second call `divideString(line, i += 1, parametro1);`

```
a = strtok(line, parametro);//not find parametro return `a=line`(top)
...
a = strtok(NULL, parametro);//a=`NULL`
...
string1 = (char) *a;//*(NULL) seg fault!!
```

---

**to update**

The set together and cease to call(`divideString`) every member of one.

E.g.

```
void stringToContaBancaria(char line[], contaBancaria *p, char para1[], char para2[]){
    char *a, *endp;
    //To convert to int from numeric strings for example it use strtol
    p->id.a    = strtol(a=strtok(line, para1), &endp, 10);
    if(*endp) fprintf(stderr, "id.a not number : %s\n", a);
    p->id.b    = strtol(a=strtok(NULL, para1), &endp, 10);
    if(*endp) fprintf(stderr, "id.b not number : %s\n", a);
    p->id.c    = strtol(a=strtok(NULL, para2), &endp, 10);
    if(*endp) fprintf(stderr, "id.c not number : %s\n", a);
    p->saldo   = strtol(a=strtok(NULL, para2), &endp, 10);
    if(*endp) fprintf(stderr, "saldo not number : %s\n", a);
    p->credito = strtoul(a=strtok(NULL, para2), &endp, 10);
    if(*endp) fprintf(stderr, "credito not number : %s\n", a);
}

void contaFill(char line[]){
    contaBancaria * p = malloc(sizeof(contaBancaria));
    char parametro1[] = "-";
    char parametro2[] = " ";//" \n"?
    stringToContaBancaria(line, p, parametro1, parametro2);
    printf("%d - %d - %d %d %hu\n", p->id.a, p->id.b, p->id.c, p->saldo, p->credito);
    //free(p);//deallocate! 
}
```

---

**it gives me seg error**

```
    //less a(=strtok return value) becomes to NULL element when reading is less than expected.
    p->credito = strtoul(a=strtok(NULL, para2), &endp, 10);
    if(*endp) fprintf(stderr, "credito not number : %s\n", a);
```

E.g. change to

```
    if(NULL!=(a=strtok(NULL, para2))){
        p->credito = strtoul(a, &endp, 10);
        if(*endp)fprintf(stderr, "credito not number : %s\n", a);
    } else
        fprintf(stderr, "credito not exist\n");
```

but I think the check for the before time rather than do between the reading these necessary items whether there is.

---

**make a simple pre-check**

```
#include <ctype.h>

int isInvalidRecord(char line[]){
//[number]-[number]-[number][space][number][space][number][space*]
//521-71750-4 500000 25000[newline]
    int i=0, j;
    while(isdigit(line[i]))++i;
    if(i==0 || line[i]!='-') return 1;//1st item bad
    j=++i;
    while(isdigit(line[i]))++i;
    if(i==j || line[i]!='-') return 2;
    j=++i;
    while(isdigit(line[i]))++i;
    if(i==j || line[i]!=' ') return 3;
    j=++i;
    while(isdigit(line[i]))++i;
    if(i==j || line[i]!=' ') return 4;
    j=++i;
    while(isdigit(line[i]))++i;
    if(i==j || (line[i]!='\0' && !isspace(line[i]))) return 5;
    return 0;//ALL OK
}

void contaFill(char line[]){
    contaBancaria * p = malloc(sizeof(contaBancaria));
    char parametro1[] = "-";
    char parametro2[] = " ";//" \n"?
    int check = isInvalidRecord(line);
    if(check == 0)//0 is OK
        stringToContaBancaria(line, p, parametro1, parametro2);
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "%s %d item(near) is bad\n", line, check);
    printf("%d - %d - %d %d %hu\n", p->id.a, p->id.b, p->id.c, p->saldo, p->credito);
    //free(p);//deallocate! 
}
```

Comment: sory i did not understand this so how can i update my code to do the same and that is "123-55555-1 10000 0" each number box should be in a diferent variable in a total of 5 variables in the list. thx

Comment: @RicardoSacramento i was write example of  code modification.

Comment: @RicardoSacramento  sample last record `191-11999-7 1200` only four item. you need to check like this?

Comment: Thx for your post and yes i need to restrict if the file all camps are they if they are not so the entry is invalid and i dont put it on the list. Also the last camp the credito is unsigned short int how do i conver this?

Comment: @RicardoSacramento `strtoul` is used the same way for `unsigned short int`.

Comment: I implemented everything like you said but when the text file misses one value ex(the last entry) it gives me seg error when entering in the stringToContaBancaria. From my point of view this could be an erro inside de function because we are dividing the string in a not dynamic way, but i've put some prints to see where go code goes and were it stops and i've put one above de calling of the function stringToContaBancaria and one when it enters and it gives me seg error after the first print any thoughts?

Comment: @RicardoSacramento  return value of strtok is saving it to variable a ,  but there needs to be to check it as this will be NULL if the item is less than expected.

Answer (score 2):

Your code crashes here:

```
string1 = (char) *a;
```

You'd see this in any debugger.  First, note that the `(char)` cast here is unnecessary.  But the real problem is that `a` is sometimes `NULL` and so cannot be dereferenced.  You need to figure out what you want to do in that case.

Answer (score -1):

Well there were plenty of problems in your code.I have tried to fix all the bugs and its working fine no, here is the improvements i made :

Here

The function `strtok();` returns the pointer type which you were assigning to `a` whereas it should be assigned to `*a`

I have written any other improvements in comments(//).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct identificador_s
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;

} identificador;

typedef struct contaBancaria_s
{
  identificador id;
  int saldo;
  unsigned short int credito;
  struct contaBancaria_s * proximo;

} contaBancaria;

contaBancaria * contaP = NULL;
char contas[] = "contas.txt";
char movimentos[] = "movimentos.txt";

char divideString(char line[], int contagem, char parametro[])
{
  int i = 0;
  char *a = NULL;
  char string1;
  *a = strtok(line, parametro);
  while (i != contagem)
  {
    *a = strtok(NULL, parametro);
    i++;
  }
  string1 = (char) *a;
  return string1;

}

void contaFill(char line[])
{
  printf("passo -2");
  contaBancaria *p=malloc(sizeof(contaBancaria));
  printf("passo 0");
  int i = 0;
  char parametro1[] = "-";
  char parametro2[] = " ";
  p->id.a = (int) divideString(line, i, parametro1);
  printf("passo 1");
  p->id.b = (int) divideString(line, i += 1, parametro1);
  printf("passo2");
  p->id.c = (int) divideString(line, i += 1, parametro1);
  printf("passo 3");
  /*if(!(validaIdentificador(p-id.a,p->id.b,p-id.c))){
   return;
   }*/
  p->saldo = (int) divideString(line, i += 1, parametro2);
  printf("passo 4");
  p->credito = (int) divideString(line, i += 1, parametro2);
  printf("passo 5");
  printf("%d - %d - %d %d %d", p->id.a, p->id.b, p->id.c, p->saldo, p->credito);
}

void loadFile(char fileType[])
{
  FILE * fp;
  fp = fopen(fileType, "r");
  int size = 100;
  char buffer[100];
  char string1[100];
  if (fp)
  {
    while (fgets(buffer, 100, fp) != NULL)
    {
      puts(buffer);
      if (strcmp(fileType, "contas.txt") == 0)
      {
        contaFill(buffer);
      }
    }
      }
  fclose(fp);// file should close outside the if statement 
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  loadFile(contas);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C there is **no** need to cast the result of `malloc()`. Even more it is **not** recommended to do so: http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/694576

Comment: So why does it show the error :" wrong definition of malloc()" @alk

Comment: @alk well yeah, actually problem with the code was in ,not declaring the pointer variable p, and i took it the other way, thanks for guidance and that link,eventually i made the correction

Comment: aaah!! downvote is too discouraging, everybody does not become a genius like the guys here just overnight.mistakes do happen,but the main part is too improvise from that mistake.its too harsh, anyway i take it.

Comment: I think you got the downvote, for implying things, that were not necessarily the OP's intention: "... whereas it should be assigned to *a". By C it is also perfectly alright to do `char string1, * a = strtok; string1=*a; return string1`. Whether it makes sense or not is the decision of the author in the end. `char * a = NULL; *a = strtok(...)` would be UB in any case.

Comment: Well,may be,but it showed error on my system so i thought it better to point out the errors also.

Comment: The OP's code is 100% correct in terms of syntax and grammer (besides the total lack of `#include`s, which I'd consider be a copy&paste error). I'd say you'd better be off to go over your proposals again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32213/discussion-between-phifounder-and-alk)